# Mysql explain - case study

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following explain info:

```
1   PRIMARY             <derived2>  ALL         NULL                        NULL            NULL    NULL                    15  
1   PRIMARY             j           eq_ref      PRIMARY                     PRIMARY         4       tmp.sel_job_id          1   
1   PRIMARY             jd          ref         code                        code            768     test_query.j.j_code     2   Using index
2   DERIVED             t           index       NULL                        date_2          9       NULL                    15  Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  jtl         eq_ref      Multiple_keys,tester_id     Multiple_keys   8       test_query.t.id         1   Using where; Using index
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  jtl         eq_ref      Multiple_keys,tester_id     Multiple_keys   8       test_query.t.id         1   Using where; Using index
```

T table has over 55k records and jtl table over 60k records, j table has over 100 records and jd 30 records.

My query is:

```
SELECT temp_tbl.*, j.name AS job_name, jd.code AS job_details_code FROM ( 
    SELECT t.*, ( 
        SELECT jtl.job_id FROM job_tester_link jtl
        WHERE t.id = jtl.tester_id AND 
            t.id NOT IN (11220012, 11218876, 11340156) AND 
            jtl.job_id = '20' AND 
            t.active = 'Y' LIMIT 1
        ) sel_job_id 
        FROM tester t 
        WHERE ( 
            SELECT jtl.job_id 
            FROM job_tester_link jtl 
            WHERE t.id = jtl.tester_id AND 
                t.id NOT IN (11220012, 11218876, 11340156) AND 
                jtl.job_id = '20' AND 
                t.active = 'Y' 
                LIMIT 1
        ) IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY t.date DESC 
        LIMIT 0,15 
    ) temp_tbl 
LEFT JOIN job j ON temp_tbl.sel_job_id = j.id 
LEFT JOIN job_details jd ON j.j_code = jd.code;
```

My problem is the execution time (over 3 secs). How can this query be improved?
Thanks.

Comment: The first place to look is the nested where clause.  How long does just running the inner select take.  It looks like you might be able to replace the nested where clause with a left join where jtl.job_id is not null

Comment: "NOT IN" is a classic performance buster.  have you tested your code WITHOUT it?  please post table structures to better analyze what could be happening.  also, you have "NOT IN" twice, where it could be applied only once (if you wrote a view and then applied NOT IN to said view, for example.

Comment: this query is a huge mess... im surprised it executes that fast... the whole bulk of the query is a correlated subquery which means it has to execute the number of rows in the table times itself... you should change the query